# Says Java Is Installed, But It Isn't

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos, minecraft-launcher

I've been installing Java 8 on my Mac time and time again, but whenever I try to launch Minecraft, on the launcher page, it crashes and says that I don't have Java installed. I don't know what to do, so is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: The launcher tries Java 6 for Mac by default. If you don't have that installed, you'll need to manually call the launcher with Java 8 using the `jar` command in Terminal. If you're willing to do so, I can provide some guidance.

Comment: @StuartWagner That would be appreciated, I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: Well, first of all, you'll need to make sure you can actually run `java` in Terminal.app. If not, uninstall any version of Java you have and install the latest Java 1.8 SDK. After that (and maybe a reboot), you should get something intelligible from `java -version`. At that point, you can run something like `java -jar /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/Resources/Java/Bootstrap.jar` to get your launcher. You might also need to edit all your profiles and point the Executable option to the 1.8 SDK binary.

Comment: @StuartWagner Post that as an answer, not a comment! (Also gives you better formatting options.)

Comment: @StuartWagner Just a side note, he shouldn't install the SDK (Software Development Kit), but rather the JRE (Java Runtime Environment). Otherwise, great answer! Post it in the answers section!

Comment: @APCoding Hmm, I checked and the JRE does not provide the necessary command line tools for Java. So OP does, in fact, need the JDK. Anyway, I'll post all this as an answer.

Comment: The title and question are contradictory.

Answer (score 11):

When trying to run Minecraft on OS X systems, the launcher tries to use Java 6 for Mac by default. This is because Apple used to ship their own version of Java (SE 6) with the operating system (mainly for security reasons). In recent versions of OS X, however, Java is no longer included, hence the error message you're seeing.

There are two ways to solve this issue.

---

## Option 1 - Install Java 6

You could give the launcher what it wants and install the legacy [Apple Java SE 6 runtime](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572). Installing Apple Java 6 will allow the launcher to open; however, your Minecraft instances will also run on Java 6, since that is what the game looks for by default unless you override the executable (more on that under Option 2, Step 4 below).

The issue with this option is that you have to introduce old technology to make things work. Having everything run on the latest and greatest Java 8 patch would make everything a whole lot cleaner and easier, which brings us to...

---

## Option 2 - Just use Java 8, already! (recommended)

As you've discovered, installing Java 8 alone won't do you any good. The launcher stalls because it can't find the Java runtime it needs. So, to get around this, you'll need to manually call the launcher using command line. This solution is a bit technical, but I'll try to walk you through it.

### Step 1

Install the Java 8 JDK. On Oracle's [Java SE Downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), in the *Java Platform, Standard Edition* box, click **Download** by "JDK".

On the next page, in the **first** list of downloads, check "Accept License Agreement" and click on the download link for "Mac OS X x64".

Save the file, open it, and run the installer package once the disk image pops up.

### Step 2

Make sure you can run Java via command line. Open up Terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal.app), type `java -version` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The command should return something intelligible like this:

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

If you get something like `No Java runtime present, requesting install`, you may have installed the JRE (you need the JDK).

### Step 3

Now that you have the Java 8 CLI, you can execute the Minecraft launcher `jar`. Back in Terminal, run the following:

```
java -d64 -jar /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/Resources/Java/Bootstrap.jar
```

*Note: This assumes you have the `Minecraft.app` file in your Applications folder. Make sure the path is correct.*

If all went well, you should now see your launcher. Hooray!

### Step 4

Make sure that all your profiles point to a Java 1.8 JDK binary under the **Executable** option. It should look something like this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
```

You should now be able to launch the game.

### Step 5

At this point, you can play Minecraft using Java 8. However, opening up Terminal and running a command every time you want to play is a bit tedious. To get around that, you can create your own application that will do it for you.

#### Method 1

Create an Automator workflow. Open Automator (Applications > Automator.app), and choose the "Application" workflow ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOYlc.png)).

In the Library panel on the left, search for "shell" and double-click **Run Shell Script** ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se4Qz.png)). In the newly created modal field, add the command we used to execute the Minecraft launcher back in *Step 3*, along with an interpreter directive, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -d64 -jar /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/Resources/Java/Bootstrap.jar
```

Next, click **Run** in the top right of the window as a test. The Minecraft launcher should open up. Quit it, go back to Automator, and save the project into Applications as `Minecraft Launcher.app`. You can now quit Automator.

#### Method 2 (recommended)

Create an app package. In a plain Text Editor document, add the command we used to execute the Minecraft launcher back in *Step 3*, along with an interpreter directive, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -d64 -jar /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/Resources/Java/Bootstrap.jar
```

Next, save the file as `launcher.sh` to your Desktop folder. Back in Terminal, run the following commands in order:

```
mkdir -p /Applications/Minecraft\ Launcher.app/Contents/MacOS
mv ~/Desktop/launcher.sh /Applications/Minecraft\ Launcher.app/Contents/MacOS/Minecraft\ Launcher
chmod +x /Applications/Minecraft\ Launcher.app/Contents/MacOS/Minecraft\ Launcher
```

<sub>Credit: Based on a [terrific little script](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps) by Thomas Alyott and modified by Mathias Bynens.</sub>

*Note: This assumes you saved the `launcher.sh` file to your Desktop folder. Make sure the path is correct.*

If all the commands succeeded, they will have created a `Minecraft Launcher.app` in Applications.

### Step 6

With all that done, you should now have a working launcher app that will let you play Minecraft using Java 8. There's just one more thing you can do to make it even better.

1. Right-click on the good old `Minecraft.app` and select "Get Info".
2. Click on the big icon in the top left, copy it using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, and close the window.
3. Right-click on the new `Minecraft Launcher.app` and again select "Get Info".
4. Click the icon in the top left again, paste with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, and close the window.

Awesome. Now it'll look great in your Dock!

---

Hopefully I've covered everything in enough detail. If you have any questions, leave a comment and I'll try my best to help.

Happy Minecrafting!

Comment: Came here wanting to get Minecraft working, and ended up learning how to make packages on a Mac (Windows guy here), +1 for great tutorial!